# Magento 2: Delete data in custom module

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, controllers, resource-model, delete

I need to delete my custom table data, I tried below code, but its not works for me.

**my table:**

```
test_id  product_id  testing

1           15       12345
```

**my code:**

```
    try{
        $model = $this->zipcodeFactory->create();

        $modelcollection = $this->zipcodeFactory->create()->getCollection();

        foreach($modelcollection as  $modeldata){


            $model->load($modeldata['test_id']);
            $model->delete();
        }

    }catch (Exception $e){

    }
```

Suggest Me What i Miss in this code.

Comment: Let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: Thanks @PrincePatel ,  my custom module issue, now fixed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter` class for massDelete

```
protected $zipcodeFactory;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Ui\Component\MassAction\Filter $filter,
    \Vendor\Module\Model\ResourceModel\Class\zipcodeFactory $zipcodeFactory,
    \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
) {
    $this->filter            = $filter;
    $this->zipcodeFactory = $zipcodeFactory;
    parent::__construct($context);
}

public function execute()
{
    try {
        $logCollection = $this->filter->getCollection($this->zipcodeFactory->create());

        foreach ($logCollection as $item) {
            $item->delete();
        }

        echo "Items Deleted"; exit;

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your ans :)

Comment: Is it possible to addFieldToFilter by product_id and record delete without foreach ? @PrincePatel

Answer (score 2):

If you want avoid do a foreach, you can use a **collection walk**.

```
$modelcollection->walk('delete');
```